# Return default constructed or void from template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, invoke-result

I have a function that wraps another call with exception handling. Most invocation doesn't return anything (void) but for some invocation the function may return an int or the like. This works fine except Im left struggling with the *default* return val or `return void`.

Im currently looking at something like the following

```
template<class T> struct member_function_trait;
template<class T, class R> struct member_function_trait<R T::*> { using type = T; using ret = R; };



template<auto f, class T, typename... Args>
auto DispatchImpl(T* obj, Args&&... args) {
  try {
    return (static_cast<typename member_function_trait<decltype(f)>::type*>(obj)->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
    //handled exception
  }
  return member_function_trait<decltype(f)>::ret; //<--- how to return default constructed or 'void' here ?
}
```

Compile error:

```
error C2275: 'member_function_trait<void (__cdecl MyClass::* )(void)>::ret': illegal use of this type as an expression
```

Im stuck as to how to proceed with the issue. Is there some simpel trick Im overlooking ? (I hope so)

Comment: `member_function_trait<decltype(f)>::ret()`?

Comment: @geza that seems not working with `void`- gives the error: error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'void (void)'

Comment: @darune I think you mixed up `member_function_trait<decltype(f)>::ret()` and `member_function_trait<decltype(f)>::ret{}`.

Comment: how you trying to use this?

Comment: I think that you have a bug. In `member_function_trait`, `R` is not the return type. At least, if you instantiate it with a member function, it will be a function type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your trait is not quite correct, because `ret` will be the function type, not its return type. You probably meant this:

```
template<class T, class R, class... A>
struct member_function_trait<R (T::*)(A...)>
{
  using type = T;
  using ret = R;
};
```

After this, just creating `ret()` will give you precisely what you want:

```
// In DispatchImpl:
return typename member_function_trait<decltype(f)>::ret();
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb123a8e4b930d49)

Comment: When I try that I get "error C2672: 'default_constructed': no matching overloaded function found"

Comment: @darune Because your trait is wrong; answer edited.

Comment: Why `default_constructed`? Is is not needed. `return void();` is a perfectly valid expression.

Comment: Yeah, `default_constructed` isn't needed unless you wan't/need brace-init

Comment: @darune: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1114r0.html#2351 This is fixed in the standard, but no major compiler implemented the fix yet.

Comment: Issue is that we need all traits variant (combination of cv qualifier, ref qualifier, noexcept, C-ellipsis). `using Ret = decltype(static_cast<typename member_function_trait<decltype(f)>::type*>(obj)->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));` with `return Ret();` might be simpler if traits is not reused.